# Как передать данные с NavigationDrawer в Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer, android-bundle

Передаю в Activity данные через Bundle c NavigationDrawer в Fragment,но
при считывании Bundle он  null

Activity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout;
    private ListView myDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle myDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence myDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence myTitle;
    private String[] viewsNames;
    public FragmentManager passfragmentManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTitle = getTitle();
        myDrawerTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.menu);

        passfragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


        viewsNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.views_array);
        myDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        myDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


        myDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, viewsNames));


        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        myDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, myDrawerLayout, R.string.open_menu, R.string.close_menu) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myTitle);

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myDrawerTitle);

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        myDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(myDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            displayView(0);
        }

        myDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(
                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id
        ) {

            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
               // sendToFragmentBundle();
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
                sendToFragmentBundle();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ThirdFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            myDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            myDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(viewsNames[position]);
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(myDrawerList);

        } else {

            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }



    public void sendToFragmentBundle()
    {
        //----------------------------------------

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();


        bundle.putString("name", "<<<<<<I Am Bundle From Activity it is WORK >>>>>>>>");


        SecondFragment fragobj=new SecondFragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragobj)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (myDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        boolean drawerOpen = myDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(myDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        myTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myTitle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        myDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Fragment.class
В TextView выводит "BUNDLE NULL"

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs_SecondFragment";    
    Bundle bundle;    
     TextView txtFrg;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        txtFrg = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);

        bundle = this.getArguments();

            if (bundle != null) {
                String myValue = bundle.getString("name");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, " ----------->Fragment  myBundle contain  "  + myValue );

                txtFrg.setText("Bundle contain"+myValue);     

            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, " ----------->Fragment  myBundle contain  " + "NULL");

                txtFrg.setText("BUNDLE NULL");
            }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильно. Так и должно быть. В процедуре sendToFragmentBundle Вы создаете фрагмент, присваиваете аргумент и выводите фрагмент в активити. Далее, в завершении процедуры displayView Вы выводите в активити уже совсем другой фрагмент:

```
case 1:
           // sendToFragmentBundle();
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            sendToFragmentBundle();
            break;
```

*** ваш код ***

```
if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

*** ваш код ***

Вам необходимо переделать процедуру sendToFragmentBundle. Либо подавая ей в параметрах созданный фрагмент, либо преобразовать процедуру в функцию.

```
public Fragment sendToFragmentBundle()
{
    //----------------------------------------

    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();


    bundle.putString("name", "<<<<<<I Am Bundle From Activity it is WORK >>>>>>>>");


    SecondFragment fragobj=new SecondFragment();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragobj;
}

case 1:
           // sendToFragmentBundle();
            fragment = sendToFragmentBundle();

            break;
```